# Why is my dblink trigger not updating?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis, dblink

I have setup a trigger on my table to update inserted rows using a dblink. I used dblink because want the trigger to update the row async.

I have tested the dblink update in pgAdmin SQL query tool succesfully. However, when I insert a row the trigger runs but no rows are updated.

Is there something I'm missing regarding dblink?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION locates_data.async_update_geom()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$


  BEGIN  
    -- as this is an after trigger, NEW contains all the information we need even for INSERT
    perform dblink('dbname=devtable00 host=10.1.1.98 port=5432 user=admin password=*****', 'update locates_data.request set geom =  ST_Transform(ST_setSRID(ST_MakePoint('||NEW.longitude||','||NEW.latitude||'), 4326),3857) where request_pk = '||NEW.request_pk||'');
    RAISE NOTICE 'UPDATING geo data for %, [%,%]' , NEW.request_pk, NEW.latitude, NEW.longitude;    
    RETURN NEW; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
  END;


$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION locates_data.async_update_geom()
```

Comment: Your dblink use looks fine to me. Can you search database logs for this query and see that it looks like you expect it to?

Comment: I've set the database log on 'notice' level.  Nothing is showing in the logs.